# UTF-8 problems in Grails 2.4 with russian lang

Tags: eclipse, grails, utf-8

I started a new project in grails 2.4 version and when I write something in russian into gsp files, browser render the page with uncorrect symbols. in gsp files I have `charset=utf-8` and `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>` this line. in Config.groovy

```
grails {
  views {
    gsp {
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
        htmlcodec = 'xml' 
        codecs {
            expression = 'html' 
            scriptlet = 'html' 
            taglib = 'none' 
            staticparts = 'none' 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and I change encoding to UTF-8 for whole project in Eclipse Project properties. what is wrong, please, help.

Comment: try changing the encoding for each GSP-file

Comment: @injecteer not working

Comment: Are you running any Linux distribution? If so, could you execute the *file* command with any of the GSP pages as argument?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the problem was with tomcat. I changed tomcat configuration fot utf-8